# Access DOM attribute with XML namespace on Freemarker template

Tags: freemarker

I have the following XML.

```
<n:wmi xmlns:inventory="http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/mp/v1/item/ItemInventory.xsd" >
<items processMode="INCREMENTAL">
  <item partnerItemId="SM-290754-US">
    <action>UPDATE</action>
    <inventory:availability code="AC" onHandQty="124" />
  </item>
</items>
```

I want to access the "code" attribute in Freemarker template. Following is my freemarker template.

I tried the following templates. But none of them are working.

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"inventory":"http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/mp/v1/item/ItemInventory.xsd"}>${item["inventory:availability[@code]"]}
```

and

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"inventory":"http://www.example.com/XMLSchema/mp/v1/item/ItemInventory.xsd"}>${item["inventory:availability.@code"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more investigation. The correct xpath will be

```
${item["inventory:availability/@code"]}
```